# Python-Fab not reading value from file

Tags: python, sed, subprocess, fabric

sed command not reading value from file.

```
with open('file.txt') as f:
 content = f.read()
subprocess.call("sed -i '/name/s/$/%s /' copy_vmlist" % content ,shell=True)
```

above one is not working.sed command should search for the 'name' in copy_vmlist and append the content(jega) of file.txt to next colmun.

```
Content of file.txt:
jega

Content of copy_vmlist:
Age
name
degree

Expected output in copy_vmlist:
Age
name jega
degree
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your sed command arguments. I guess you wanted to replace the "name" string to "jega" in the "copy_vmlist" file. Try it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess

with open('file.txt') as f:
  content = f.read().strip()
  cmd = "sed -i 's/name/%s/' copy_vmlist" % content
  subprocess.call(cmd ,shell=True)
```

Edit:

After your edit, you need this:

```
cmd = "sed -i 's/name/name %s/' copy_vmlist" % content
```

Comment: thanks for the response. i have edited my question.Please check!! It will be very grateful if you can help me to find solution!!

Comment: The solution is easier than you thought. I have edited the answer. Have a nice day :)

Comment: No luck!! not working it showing same error 'sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command'.      then in output no need of caps N in name. that was typo error.

Comment: Haha, than replace the "Name" with "name" in the source. But I have edited again, try that :)

Comment: I tried , but getting same error :(    'sed: -e expression #1, char 22: unterminated `s' command'  .  Whenever am passing values from file, am getting this error. Please suggest any solution!!!

Comment: I think you have deleted the '/' charater at the end of this: 's/name/name %s/'

Comment: No Miklos...'/' is there....i am trying with exactly what you mentioned.

Comment: Interesting it works well on my system. Could you show me the source with pastebin?

https://pastebin.com/

Comment: If i am trying with normal variable its working as expected. whenever reading value from file , it is showing error.

Comment: Haha, I have found the problem! You get this error if you have a newline after the "jega" in the file.txt. Do you need that newline?

Comment: The strip() will remove that unused newline.

Comment: Ok Miklos, i added content = f.read().strip(). Now error not coming. But 'jega' is not printing in copy_vmlist file..

Comment: 'name' or "Name"? Hehe :D

Comment: But you forgot to give me the link of that :D

Comment: The pastebin generates a link after you upload the file. You need to share that link. Without that I will not see the source.

Comment: sorryyyy https://pastebin.com/u7uJXFeE      i will run the code using fab.  fab idle_users

Comment: I have checked the block under the idle_users function. That works fine for me. So I think the bug is not in that. Maybe your copy_vmlist file did not contain the "name" line or the idle_users() function was not called. In the last case check it with a print inside of that function.

Comment: i have double checked, copy_vmlist have name line. i am running code by calling idel_users fab task (fab idle_users). when i am giving 'print content', its printing jega.  any other way to achieve this ?? :(

Comment: Look, I just modified what you uploaded to the pastebin. Try it, I am sure it will work:

https://pastebin.com/K62DkC6h

Comment: You are wellcome. Then please set this answer as a solution, maybe that will be useful for others. Have a nice day :)